# How to make the Jenkins build output as downloadable from Jenkins server machine itself?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins. i have configured the Jenkins "Free Style" project and executing a power shell a script to get an executable application(Exe) as output. i have searched for some of the plugins to make the Jenkins output (exe) as downloadable from the Jenkins server machine itself as an artifact link(download link). But i found the Jenkins plugins to copy the archive files, upload to ftp and some other plugins.

So, Could anyone please suggest me is there any option or plugin available to make the each Jenkins build output file as downloadable from the Jenkins server machine by keeping it in a server machine some other place?

Answer (score 1):

A simple option would be to copy the artifact to the `userContent` directory in Jenkins. This is found under `$JENKINS_HOME`.
Once artifact is there, you can have a static link to it in the form of

`http://<jenkins-host>:<port>/userContent/<your-artifact.exe>`

I hope this helps.